# JAXBContext#newInstance in java11 RCP application

Tags: java, jaxb, java-11, rcp

I am migrating an existing `Eclipse RCP` application from Java8 to Java11.
Therefore, the JAXB plugin needs to be added manually now. If anyone is looking for a good example, I found this one: https://github.com/vogellacompany/eclipsercp-jaxb-java11

There, the JAXBContext is instantiated like so:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Bookstore.class.getPackageName(), Bookstore.class.getClassLoader());
```

Is there any way to get the factory working by only passing the class? Like so:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Bookstore.class);
```

In the second case we get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moxy implementation offers an explicit factory to create the JAXBcontext: `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory#createContext`